# How to Query ñ in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a problem ñ did not display from my database..

i need to query it but it returns a result like this `SAÃ±ES` instead of `sañes`;

> Is there any solution to just Query it and return the word sañes?

Any Idea would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your database/table collation? Do you see the word right in the actual database and it screws up as output, or is it screwed up in the db itself?

Comment: Im not sure, but i think its a Charset-Problem. Which collation you use?

Comment: i'll check but it has a word saÃ±es.. what should i do? cant modify the database coz i don't have a permission to update it.. im just reading fetching data.

Comment: Thanks guys but i got the solution..

Answer (score 1):

I'll try this solution but it works..

```
REPLACE(column_name,'Ã±','ñ')
```